# NetBeans hangs up while creating a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans and I'm trying to create a new Rails project trought the wizard, so while I click the finish button, it creates the folder structure but the wizard never finish working and doesn't show nothing on the Projects view.

It just happens when I set up a *Sqlite3* DB.

I'm using Rails 3.0.7

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have always struggled to create Rails projects using the internal netbeans wizard. Usually I find it easier to create the rails app from the command line:

```
rails your_app_name
```

This will create a new folder your_app_name in your current location, and then I create a new project within Netbeans by selecting the 'Ruby on Rails Application with Existing sources' option. And select the freshly created your_app_name folder for the Project folder.

I have found Netbeans to be less reliable with rails 3+ applications than the 2+ and find that run most rails commands directly from the terminal/command prompt.

Comment: Yes, If i use rails 2+ instead of rails 3+ it works without issues, so I actually use "rails new my_app_name" in my command prompt but I would like to solve this issue. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Nucklear Unfortunately NetBeans has dropped Ruby on Rails support - so updates for 3+ might take a while... http://goo.gl/d85Eq

Comment: Oh, that's the reason then... Do you know another IDE with SVN, Trac and RoR3 support? Previows versions of NetBeans should work with RoR3? Thanks

Comment: @Nucklear I recently started using http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html it isn't free, but have been impressed with it thus far. Don't know what you mean about Trac support though?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. With Trac support I mean if I could sync trac tickets with pieces of code located on subversion and manage everything throught the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

do you have sqlite3 installed? Anyways people will be able to help you if you can post the netbeans log. Go to the command line and run netbeans from the command line. Then you can see a lot of output/logging info.

Comment: Yes I have sqlite3 installed, now I cant upload the log because I'm at work. With run NetBeans from prompt you mean just execute the program and check the output or I need some parameters?

Comment: yep just execute it and post the output. i have found it very helpful in debugging.